# Create and deploy custom mediator in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, mediator

I have created custom mediator with Factory and Serializer classes. Created jar with \META-INF\services\ files and put it to dropins folder.

But after restart when I deployed test proxy with my mediator, I always get error like this:

```
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element :
at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:218)
```

It looks like ESB  isn't able to find the Factory class. Where is my mistake& And may be someone has working example custom mediator with factory and serializer clases?

Comment: have you tried putting the jar in the lib folder?

Comment: Answer for this can be found by going through below SO question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365515/wso2-class-mediator-not-work

Comment: Who did you created the jar? Did you manually create the MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: I tried to create new mediator as an OSGI bundle. In this case I have to put my jar only in dropins folder.

Comment: I created jar using maven

Comment: I found temporary solution in my case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675691/how-to-implement-a-custom-mediator-with-its-own-xml-configuration   it`s works